# Aapche2 server under Ubuntu 16.04 stop working after upgrade from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, 16.04, upgrade, apache2

I recently upgraded a server based on Ubuntu server 14.04 to 16.04 x64
After upgrade i cannot access my web server using either https or http
under /var/log/apache2 , i got following error below , and my deafault-ssl.conf i got my self signed certificate as follows below ,any idea how to fix it ?
Please advise
Thanks

```
   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache-selfsigned.key
```

Apache log

```
    [Thu Oct 06 16:12:06.518074 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10550] AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Oct 06 16:12:06.518114 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10550] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share the command you ran to generate the CSR? What did you enter for the "Common Name?

reference : [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority)

Comment: Sorry , i don't remember , its was long time ago, its used to work like that more than a year , do you have any suggestion to properly create self signed cert?

Comment: you can read reference and regenerate CSR